# call of overloaded 'qHash(const double&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I get this error when I try to convert a QList to a QSet.

```
QList<double> x_pts;
x_pts << 4.1;
x_pts << 2.2;
x_pts << 2.2;
x_pts << 1.3;
qSort(x_pts);
QSet<double> list = x_pts.toSet();
```

Any idea why i am getting this error? It works fine if I change the type to int or double*. But double should work as well.

All i want to do is to remove duplicates from my list. I want to find a way to do it without iterating the list myself.

Any help in removing this error or another function to remove duplicates will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rush

Comment: Can you provide exact compiler message?

Comment: Could you provide your platform and Qt version as well? This looks like a Qt Bug.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler error is due to the fact that Qt simply hasn't defined a qHash() function that takes in a double.  The reason for this is that it is generally a bad idea to use floating point numbers as keys in a hash (in this case your QSet uses a hash internally).

You say you are trying to remove duplicates, but the concept of equality among floating point numbers is fuzzy in C++, as it turns out to be quite difficult to say that any two floating point numbers are truly equal.

(See [the C++ faq regarding this subject](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17))

The solution to your problem is going to be either:

a) Don't use floating point numbers

b) Define your own qHash function that satisfies the requirements of your program in a way that is satisfactory.  Defining a `qHash( double )` in your implentation file would be sufficient.